# GeoDataFrame.plot doesn't work as expected with column color

Tags: plot, geopandas, osmnx

I have a GeoPandas GeoDataframe containing buildings' geometries. For each building, I calculated the distance to a given LineString, and added the column "dist" to the GeoDataFrame.

I would like to plot in white buildings below a given distance and in red those above the same distance. But for some reason, the colours got mixed up [image: (img_03.png).]

Here is my code:

```
buildings['color'] ='black'

buildings_small = buildings.loc[(buildings['dist'] < 0.0020)]
buildings_small.loc[(buildings_small.dist >= 0.0010) & (buildings_small.dist <= 0.0020), 'color'] = 'red'
buildings_small.loc[(buildings_small.dist < 0.0010), 'color'] = 'white'
buildings_small['geometry'].plot(color = buildings_small['color'],alpha =0.5, markersize = 0.0,ax = ax)
```

I am sure the distance is properly calculated, because when I just plot:
01:

```
buildings_small = buildings.loc[(buildings['dist'] < 0.0010)]
```

I correctly get the [image: img_01.png.]

And when I plot:
02:

```
buildings_small = buildings.loc[(buildings['dist'] >= 0.0010) & (buildings['dist'] <= 0.0020)]
```

I correctly get the [image: img_02.png].

I have tried to create the 'color' column in many ways, with apply-lambda and with .at method, but no one seems to work. It should be a very simple problem, but I am really clueless right now. Moreover, if I save the GeoDataFrame and plot it on Carto, it displays correctly [image: (img_04.png).]

**EDIT**
Here goes a reproducible example. Data are retrieved directly via Osmnx:

```py
    import pandas
    import geopandas
    import osmnx as ox
    import matplotlib
    import matplotlib.colors as colors
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.transforms as transforms
    import shapely
    from shapely.geometry import MultiLineString, LineString, Point
    from shapely.ops import nearest_points
    
    #---getting the administrative boundary and related informations
    region_name = 'Bologna, Provincia di Bologna, Emilia-Romagna, Italia'
    region = ox.geocoder.geocode_to_gdf(region_name, which_result=1)
    
    #---extracting buildings and simplify GeoDataFrame
    buildings = ox.geometries.geometries_from_polygon(region['geometry'][0], tags = {'building': True})
    buildings = buildings[['geometry','building']]
    
    #---calculating building centroids and adding to the geodataframe
    b_centroids = buildings.centroid
    buildings['centroids'] = b_centroids
    
    #---creating the LINESTRING
    p1 = (11.348198,44.522814)
    p2 = (11.344315,44.501160)
    p3 = (11.356558,44.498036)
    p4 = (11.357552,44.490084)
    p5 = (11.379144,44.481843)
    trip = LineString([p1,p2,p3,p4,p5])
    
    #---calculating the nearest point on the linestring for each building, and the distance between building and its corresponding nearest point
    buildings['nearest'] = buildings.apply(lambda row: nearest_points(trip, row.centroids)[0],axis =1)
    buildings['dist'] = buildings.apply(lambda row: row.centroids.distance(row.nearest),axis =1)
    
    #---assigning colors
    buildings['color'] = 'red'
    buildings_service = buildings.loc[(buildings['dist'] < 0.0020)]
    buildings_service.loc[(buildings_service.dist >= 0.0010) & (buildings_service.dist <= 0.0020), 'color'] = 'red'
    buildings_service.loc[(buildings_service.dist < 0.0010), 'color'] = 'white'
    buildings_service.to_csv("buildings.csv", index = False)
    
    #---getting rivers
    rivers = ox.geometries.geometries_from_polygon(region['geometry'][0], tags = {'waterway': 'river'})
    
    #---plotting administrative boundary, buildings and rivers
    ax = region.plot(facecolor = '#000070',
                markersize = 0,
                figsize=(15,15))
    
    ax.set_facecolor('#2C2E2E')
    
    buildings_service['geometry'].plot(color = buildings_service['color'],
                alpha =0.5,
                markersize = 0.0,
                ax = ax)
    
    rivers.plot(edgecolor = '#67A0C3',
                linewidth = 1,
                linestyle = '-',
                markersize = 0,
                ax = ax)
    
    left = 4.0
    bottom = 4.0
    width = 4
    height = 4
    bbox = transforms.Bbox.from_bounds(left, bottom, width, height)
    
    #---save the image
    plt.savefig('GENERATED_IMAGES/img_04.png', bbox_inches = bbox, format = "png", dpi = 2400)
```

**WORKAROUND**.
I just found out that saving the GeoDataFrame to disk to .json format and reopening it makes the issue disappear.

Comment: I just searched for the docs real quick and read this page about plotting: https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/mapping.html

I don't think Geopandas expects the "color" column to be a list of colors. It'd be nice if you had a reproducible example that included a small, hard-coded dataset with simple geometries and the exact code you're using to create the plot.

Comment: @PaulH I edited my question with a reproducible example. I am aware that the 'color' keyword should be used to map colors based on numerical values, but I have seen examples of this "categorized" use. I also tried the "map" function after normalizing the 'dist' column, but with no results

Comment: I just tried to run your reproducible example with a fresh environment, and I obtain the figure you seem to want, e.g. similar to your last one. Check with a fresh virtual environment maybe to verify that nothing is messed up with you installed packages ? I was running Python 3.10, latest version of every packages, on MacOS.

Comment: I just found out that saving the GeoDataFrame to disk to .json format and reopening it makes the issue disappear. I will try it in a fresh environment though, it is a good idea